# Compliation fails with Jenkins, successful with eclipse

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins. Literally - today's my first day. So i am trying to build a legacy maven project with it to help me learn.

The project compiles successfully with eclipse and the command "mvn package". But i get the following errors when building it in jenkins :

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/bg2/.jenkins/jobs/projectA/workspace/target/generated-sources/po/com/projA/webservices/ping/HandlePing.java:[56,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Service(java.net.URL,javax.xml.namespace.QName,javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature[])
location: class javax.xml.ws.Service
```

And 8 more similar ones, just in different files.

What am i missing, how do i fix this?

Comment: Your class HandlePing contains annotations?

Comment: yes.. `@WebServiceClient` and `@WebEndpoint`

Comment: Do you have declared the version that you are compiling the code in maven? (with maven-compiler-plugin)?

Answer (score 0):

javax.xml.ws.Service is part of jaxws-api.jar, javaee-api and different vendor specific libraries.

So first you should check if your pom.xml definies a dependency to a library that contains javax.xml.ws.Service. Usually its jaxws-api.jar or javaee-api.jar.

Second do check that the local maven repository of your Jenkins is messed up. If you are in doubt configure your Jenkins job to always clean up the workspace and the local repository as well before Jenkins will run that job.

Third do check the settings.xml that is used by Jenkins and compare it with your local settings.xml. Maybe there are different configurations of remote repositories that doesn't contain the desired library.

Comment: 1 - Yes, i do have a dependency to jaxws-api: `jaxws-api-2.2.1`
2 - Jenkins uses the default maven repository.. `<USER_HOME>/.m2/repository`
3 - Jenkins uses the default maven settings.
So i see no difference!

Comment: Use a different repository than for your local build to avoid interfering with your local. Configure jenkins to cleanup this repository.